# Remove TabBar Button glow(not on image- hiding the selection tint of button)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I've created a tabbar application,I am using a custom TabBar with a backGround image.
I have finished all the parts but unable to remove the glow of tabbar button on click(i just changing the UIButton selection on click,but glow is still there)

**How to hide the glow of UITabBar Buttons(ie hiding the selection tint of buttons) ?**

Now TabBar is like this..
[image]

Need tabBar like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change tabbar tint colour

`[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];`

Comment: no..i meant the selection glow, i want to remove that effect when i click
simple words : nothing should happen on tabbar appearance when i click

an effect user should not find which button is been clicked (actually i will change button selected image for that)

Comment: do u need to change tab bar image when customer select some tab right?

Comment: no..u still did not get the real need of mine,

"on a tabbar application(any simple one) when user click on one tab,that tab button will be selected(a gray colored tint will be there right ?) I want to hide that..!!!"

Comment: only way to achieve this u need to replace the whole tabbar instead of replace  tabbaritem

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following code.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Try It.

Answer (score 2):

This will definitely  help you. Simply create an UIImage object and pass it to  `setSelectionIndicatorImage` property .

```
[yourTabbar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:1];
```

Comment: In the future, please add a description to your post and not just code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `UITabBarItem` appearance:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor yellowColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                          [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f], UITextAttributeFont,nil]
                                         forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: no..i meant the selection glow, i want to remove that effect when i click
simple words : nothing should happen on tabbar appearance when i click

an effect user should not find which button is been clicked (actually i will change button selected image for that)